# How to exclude some spec files in jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Is there any way to exclude some spec files with in a directory in jasmine?
For example, I want to exclude all spec in the extended folder from Foo folder.

````
```
├── Foo
│   ├── sub
|   |    |
|   |    |--extended
│   │         ├── a-spec.js
|   |         ├── e-spec.js
│   ├── b-spec.js
│   ├── c-spec.js
│   ├── d-spec.js
└── 
```
````

I have tried with folowing jasmin.json.But this is not working.

```
    {
    "spec_dir": "Foo/",
    "spec_files": [
        "**/*[sS]pec.js",
        "!**/extended/*.js"
    ]
}
```

Comment: hopefully this [other SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52937171/jasmine-how-to-exclude-node-modules-from-spec-coverage/56292303#56292303) should help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get information regrading this issue on jasmine [github issue](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm/issues/128).

Jasmine now accepts glob patterns like this:

```json
{
  spec_files: [
    '**/*spec.js',
    '!foo/**/*.js',
    'foo/really/*.js'
  ]
}
```