# Jasmine - How to exclude node_modules from spec coverage

Tags: node.js, jasmine

I'm in trouble excluding node_modules files from my spec_files option.

This is my jasmine.json config.

```js
{ 
  "spec_dir": "packages", 
  "spec_files": [ "**/*[sS]pec.js" ], 
  "helpers": [ "helpers/**/*.js" ],     "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false, 
  "random": true 
}
```

the spec_dir is a directory with multiple node_projects, each one has their own node_modules folder.

I've tried add '!node_modules/**/*[sS]pec.js' on the spec_files array but didn't work.

Is that a bug? Because from what i read in the docs thats the way I can exclude files from spec coverage.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I came across your [issue](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm/issues/143) and [this other SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50410351/how-to-exclude-some-spec-files-in-jasmine) then realised I had the wrong version of jasmine running. Even though I had `jasmine-core: 3.4.0` in my `package.json`, the output of `node_modules/.bin/jasmine` was still `2.8.0`. Upon inspection of the `node_modules/jasmine/package.json` I realised the executable was coming from an older version of jasmine, required by another dependency (in my case, protractor).

**tl;dr;** `npm i jasmine@~3.4.0 --save-dev` should solve your issue